# mutant-rspec with Rails 4 and Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3, mutation-testing

Doesn't seem like it's running my specs (log statements in specs/model don't show in log).

I have a fairly simple User model with standard describe blocks (describe User ...):

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec mutant -r ./config/environment --use rspec User
Module#name from: XPath::HTML did not return a String or nil. Fix your lib to support normal ruby         semantics!
Module#name from: XPath did not return a String or nil. Fix your lib to support normal ruby     semantics!
#<Method: User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection).page> does not have valid source location unable to emit subject
Mutant configuration:
Matcher:            #<Mutant::Matcher::Config match_expressions=[<Mutant::Expression: User>]     subject_ignores=[] subject_selects=[]>
Integration:        rspec
Expect Coverage:    100.00%
Processes:          8
Includes:           []
Requires:           ["./config/environment"]
Mutant configuration:
Matcher:            #<Mutant::Matcher::Config match_expressions=[<Mutant::Expression: User>]     subject_ignores=[] subject_selects=[]>
Integration:        rspec
Expect Coverage:    100.00%
Processes:          8
Includes:           []
Requires:           ["./config/environment"]
Available Subjects: 0
Subjects:           0
Mutations:          0
Kills:              0
Alive:              0
Runtime:            1.05s
Killtime:           0.00s
Overhead:           Inf%
Coverage:           0.00%
Expected:           100.00%
$
```

Comment: Does your User class contain any code within a `def` or `def self...`?